# Can a lion be fed cat food?

Tags: food, behaviour, diet, feline

Is there a correlation between eating raw meat and aggressiveness in felines and canines?

Growing up, I was always told to cook the meat I gave to my dogs and cats so as not to give them the "taste for blood". Is there truth in this myth?

And if that's the case, wouldn't the same food have the same effect on "bigger cats" ? Wouldn't it safer to feed Zoo animals cooked meat ?

Comment: I read once (I don't remember where), that captive big cats' food has to be prepared in a way similar to how they would eat in the wild. e.g. cheetahs will only eat extremely fresh meat (in the wild, they have to eat quickly because their kills are often stolen), but leopards prefer meat that's almost rotten (in the wild, they store their kills in trees for days before eating it). In other words, I suspect the reason zoos don't cook meat for big cats is because they want to mimic the animals' natural diet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks pob and better suited for skeptics. Issue with this kind of question is that the answer-er needs to prove or debunk the theory first and then start explaining why; basically a double answer imo. Better split it up I guess; prove or debunk @ skeptics and come back here with a more educated question.